# Limiting Concurrently Running Workflows

Tags: workflow, task-list

I've got a SharePoint 2007 site which is using list item workflows to direct the execution of a business process. The list items are large (100+ fields). These workflows create tasks to collect data from various assigned users. The idea is that each step populates another piece of the original list item.

Most workflows start by checking the list item, and waiting for some condition before running through it's various data collection steps.

The problem is, each item has, upon creation, 26 workflows running at once. Over time, the workflows become completed and stop, of course, but it's clear that with only a few list items, there are a lot of workflows running on the site.

**Question: Is there a better way to progressively collect this data than having all of these concurrently running workflows?**

Answer (score 0):

That is quite a lot (in my opinion). Is it possible for you to redesign these workflows and refactor it into one (or maybe 2) workflows? As these 26 workflows are kicked in for just one item, I can image that you could put all functionality into 1 workflow. Workflows in 2007 do support parallel processing (which could be the 26 parallel running processes that are currently running as separate workflows).

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. Each workflow can be grouped into 1 of 5 categories, and each workflow is meant to be executed in parallel with the others in its category. So, there is a business need to have some of these workflows running in parallel.

However, most of the workflows are running and just waiting for the list item to be categorized a certain way before continuing to their next step. Is there a way to have a workflow start another workflow, rather than each one acting as an active listener.

Comment: Look at http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/, it's a collection of useful workflow activities. There is a "Start another workflow" activity in there.